# Unable to install react native with react native elements

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, yarnpkg

React native cli globally installed version : 2.0.1

I then used `react-native init project_name` to set up a project with the native modules.

I then tried installing [React Native Elements UI Toolkit](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements) using `yarn add react-native-elements@beta` followed by `yarn add react-native-vector-icons` and then `react-native link react-native-vector-icons` as per the docs here [React Native Elements Docs](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/getting_started.html)

The install completed successfully with a package.json that looks like this

```
{
"name": "project_react_native",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
  "test": "jest"
},
"dependencies": {
  "react": "16.2.0",
  "react-native": "0.53.3",
  "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0-beta2"
  "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.5.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "babel-jest": "22.4.0",
 "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
 "jest": "22.4.0",
 "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
},
"jest": {
 "preset": "react-native"
}
}
```

I have used  the following as my default component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {Button} from 'react-native-elements';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

export default class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        // Try setting `flexDirection` to `column`.
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 
      'powderblue'}}/>
            <Button
                icon={
                    <Icon
                        name='arrow-right'
                        size={15}
                        color='white'
                    />
                }
                text='BUTTON WITH ICON'
            />
        </View>
    );
  }
};
```

This throws the following error

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 1):

[Doesn't look like you can pass a component to the icon prop](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.0/button.html#button-props).
Change your Button to something along these lines:

```
<Button
  icon={{
      name: 'arrow-right', 
      type: 'font-awesome', 
      buttonStyle: styles.someButtonStyle 
  }}
  text='BUTTON WITH ICON'
/>
```

See how it goes from there.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error in metro bundler around handling paths to direct files. The issue and workarounds have been logged over at the react-native repo.

You can follow [this](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/issues/937) and [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17610#issuecomment-357884014) github issue for further references.

The work around for solving it is

Create a `rn-cli.config.js` file in your root directory and paste in the following code.

```
const blacklist = require('metro/src/blacklist')

module.exports = {
  getBlacklistRE() {
   return blacklist([/react-native\/local-cli\/core\/__fixtures__.*/])
 },
}
```

Be sure to restart the packager.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of problem in the code just replace your code with this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';

import {Button, Icon} from 'react-native-elements';


export default class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        // Try setting `flexDirection` to `column`.
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}/>
            <Button
                icon={{  
                        name:'arrow-right',
                        size:15,
                        type: 'font-awesome',
                        color:'white',
                }}
                title='BUTTON WITH ICON'
            />
        </View>
    );
  }
};
```